# Is there a way to auto render items from the backend?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I retrieve data from the backend in a method. How can I auto render that data in a component when the app starts?

I tried with `mount` and `beforemount`.

Is there any other way?

```
state() {
    return {
        FirebaseList: []
    }
},
mutation: {
    firebaseList(state,items) {
        state.FirebaseList.push(items)
    },
},
getters: {
    getFirebaseList(state) {
        return state.FirebaseList
    }
}
```

```
beforemount() {
    return this.dataitems
},
methods: {
  dataitems() {
      db.collection("Orders")
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=> {
                // console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                var list= doc.data()
                this.$store.commit('firebaseList',list)
            });
        });
    },
}
```

This code is working, but, whenever I re-open the page, it mounts the data again and I see duplicate data on the screen.

Comment: Show the mount method you use, and the errors you have.

Comment: @MRMarkII I edit the post check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by simply checking that if the list has some items, then don't push the items. Which stopped the list from duplicating items.

```
if (this.$store.state.FirebaseList.length===0){
// run the fetch code
}
else {
return
}
```